# MySQL query with salary pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with 10000 employees. I would like to write a query to find pairs of employees where both live in California, one is a 24 year old manager, the other (any age) is not a manager. The manager must earn more than three times the other employee.

The result will be 4 columns (name1, salary1, name2, salary2)

I tried this but it just duplicates the employee.

```
select T1.name as name1, T1.salary as salary1, T2.name as name2, T2.salary as salary2
FROM Employee T1 JOIN Employee T2 on T1.eid = T2.eid
and t1.age = t2.age
and t1.name = t2.name
and t1.residenceState = t2.residenceState
and t1.startDate = t2.startDate
WHERE t1.residenceState = 'CA' and t2.residenceState = 'CA' and t1.age = 24
;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: The only way you identify a manager (ignoring age) is salary is more than 3* employee salary? How do you know who is the employees manager on these bases alone when you could have many managers who fulfil the conditions?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You have too many conditions -- and not the right ones.  You are missing the conditions on salary and manager-ness.  You have additional conditions such as on name that are not relevant.  So:

```
SELECT T1.name as name1, T1.salary as salary1, T2.name as name2, T2.salary as salary2
FROM Employee T1 JOIN
     Employee T2 
     ON T1.eid = T2.eid AND
        t1.residenceState = t2.residenceState
WHERE t1.residenceState = 'CA' AND
      t1.age = 24 AND
      t1.is_manager = 1 AND. -- or however you know who a manager is
      t1.salary > 3 * t2.salary
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gordon. 'manages' is a different table with did, and eid being the primary keys (department and employee id). This is what I came up with, but it returns 0 rows.

Comment: select T1.name as name1, T1.salary as salary1, T2.name as name2, T2.salary as salary2
FROM Employee T1 JOIN Employee T2 on T1.eid = T2.eid
JOIN manages T3 on T3.did = T3.did
and t1.residenceState = t2.residenceState
WHERE t1.residenceState = 'CA' and 
      t1.age = 24 AND
      t3.did > 0 AND
      t1.salary > 3*t2.salary
;

Answer (score 0):

You can get some potentially odd results with the criteria

```
DROP table if exists t;
create table t(name varchar(10),age int, salary int,residencestate varchar(2));

insert into t values
('aaa',24,1000,'ca'),('bbb',24,4000,'ca'),('ccc',24,5000,'ca'),('zzz',23,5000,'ca'),
('ddd',13,200,'nb'),('EEE',20,500,'nb'),
('fff',13,500,'tx'),('EEE',24,2500,'tx')
;


select T1.name as name1, t1.age age1,T1.salary as salary1, T2.name as name2, t2.age age2,T2.salary as salary2
from t t1
cross join t t2
where t2.salary > 3* t1.salary
        and t2.age = 24
        and t2.residencestate = t1.residencestate
;

+-------+------+---------+-------+------+---------+
| name1 | age1 | salary1 | name2 | age2 | salary2 |
+-------+------+---------+-------+------+---------+
| aaa   |   24 |    1000 | bbb   |   24 |    4000 |
| aaa   |   24 |    1000 | ccc   |   24 |    5000 |
| fff   |   13 |     500 | EEE   |   24 |    2500 |
+-------+------+---------+-------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```